# Java - Is there a way to declare a generic class type?

Tags: java, generics

At least in Java, I don't know if there is a way to be able to do this but, I am trying to find a no-args solution for being able to pass around a class type of an unknown generic value.

```
class MyClass<T> {
   // Trying to find something like this...
   Class<T> classValue = T.class;
   Class<T> classValue = new Class<T>();

   // Trying to avoid this, I desire a no-args constructor solution
   MyClass(Class<T> classValue) { this.classValue = classValue }
}
```

Comment: No. There is no way to achieve what you want using Java generics. This is a consequence of the way generics were implemented in Java. Specifically, type erasure.